# Comparing two lists of Strings and counting the matches, possible performance problem

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, matching

I want to count the amount of matches when comparing a List of Strings A with another List of Strings B. A contains elements from a Set Z and B is a subset of Z. A can contain duplicates but B cannot.  I want duplicates to be counted individually so 2x match with the same element from B should yield 2 counts.
List A's strings contain a prefix which i decided to cut out but i could also leave the original string elements unmodified

Example:

```
List<string> A = {"a","b","c","a"}
List<string> B = {"a", "c"}
```

matches would be 3 (two times matched with a and once matched with c)

I have a solution that should work and in very rare cases it does work but my suspicion is that due to time constraints during execution it fails 90% of the time.

```
var _A = A.Select(str => str.ToLower()).ToList(); //B can be modified for this step to be not necessary but increases the length of each string element
_A = _A.Select(str => str.Replace(" ", "")).ToList(); //B can be modified for this step to be not necessary but increases the length of each string element
_A = _A.Select(x => x.Substring("drops".Length)).ToList(); //B can be modified for this step to be not necessary but increases the length of each string element

sum = _A.Where(x => B.Any(y => y.Equals(x))).Count();
```

This is `O(A*B)` if im not mistaken.

Is there anything more i can do to reduce the time complexity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an `HashSet<string>`. It is O(1) both in [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-5.0) and [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=net-5.0).

```
var a = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "a" };
var b = new[] { "a", "c" };

var hs = new HashSet<string>(b);
var cnt = a.Count(x => hs.Contains(x));
```

This has a complexity of O(b+a), O(b) for the `Add()`, O(A) for the `Contains()`.